# exclude category in loop.php

Tags: categories

I am using twentyten theme. I am trying to exclude category 1 from author posts. I used the following code in loop.php

```
query_posts(cat='-1');
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

But no post is displaying. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misplaced the apostrophe.

```
query_posts('cat=-1'); while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Now the posts are displaying but all authors posts are displaying.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Do you want to exclude some authors as well? Or show posts from only one author?

Comment: If i click author A then the posts posted by him only display. Other authors posts should not display in author A's page.

Comment: Add the author parameter to your query, like this: query_posts('cat=-1&author=3'), where 3 is the author id.